# Why are drand48() and friends obsolete?

Tags: c, random, posix, obsolete

Why are drand48() and friends obsolete? After all, they seem superior to the standard libc rand(). Have I missed something?

The manual pages for rand() and drand48() also seem at odds. The first recommends the second, and the second states that it is obsolete and the first should be used. (Though, to be fair, a lot of people who understand the math behind PRNGs have issues with the man pages for these functions because they are poorly-worded and in some instances just wrong.)

Still, I can find no justification for the "obsolete" status.

Comment: The man page on my system says "These functions are declared obsolete by SVID 3, which states that rand(3) should be used instead.". [SVID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V_Interface_Definition) was published in 1989. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) says nothing about them being obsolete, obsolescent, or deprecated. I have no idea *why* SVID 3 would have declared them obsolete -- which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: [SVID 4](http://www.uclibc.org/docs/SysV-Interface-vol1a.pdf) documents `drand48` and friends and says nothing about them being obsolete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDTATE**: `drand48` and friends are *not* obsolescent, and the man page no longer says they are. Apparently the change was made in response to this answer (which is kinda cool).

A git repo containing the Linux man pages is here:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git

The relevant log entry is:

```
commit 3db3ecf0ff358ab86ead91d767b8ef502bffe26b
Author: Michael Kerrisk <mtk.manpages@gmail.com>
Date:   2014-09-13 20:08:10 -0700

    drand48.3: Remove crufty text about SVID 3 marking drand48() obsolete
    
    See http://bugs.debian.org/758293
    
    drand48() is in current POSIX. It's unclear why SVID 3 would
    have marked it obsolete, but that's crufty information that
    only serves to pointlessly worry people.
    
    Reported-by: Lorenzo Beretta <lory.fulgi@infinito.it>
    Signed-off-by: Michael Kerrisk <mtk.manpages@gmail.com>
```

See also this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758293, which triggered the change.

My original answer follows.

---

The man page on my system (which is from the [Linux man-pages project](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) says:

> These functions are declared obsolete by SVID 3, which states that
> `rand(3)` should be used instead.

[SVID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V_Interface_Definition) 3 was published in 1989.

[SVID 4](http://www.uclibc.org/docs/SysV-Interface-vol1a.pdf) (the link is to a 720-page PDF), published in 1995, documents `drand48`, `erand48`, `lrand48`, `nrand48`, `mrand48`, `jrand48`, `srand48`, `seed48`, and `lcong48` and, like POSIX, says nothing about them being obsolete.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html), as of 2013, says nothing about them being obsolete, obsolescent, or deprecated.

I haven't found a copy of SVID 3, so I don't know *why* it would have declared those functions obsolete, but apparently that decision was reconsidered later. The statement in the man page seems like out-of-date information. I wouldn't worry about it.

As for which function you should use, the C standard `rand()` function is the most portable (unless you recompile a different one from source code). Some `rand()` implementations are poor quality, with the low-order bits repeating in a very regular pattern; others are slightly better.

If you don't need high quality pseudo-random numbers, you might as well use `rand()` (seeded by calling `srand()` with a reasonable value, e.g., `srand(time(NULL))`).

If you do need high-quality pseudo-random numbers, it's likely that *none* of these functions is good enough, I'd advise against using any of them for cryptography, for example. You can use `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` if your system supports it. I've heard good things about the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), but I lack the expertise to comment further.

(BTW, if you do a Google search for SVID, watch out for [Svið](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svid)).

Comment: Mersenne Twister is a fabulous PRNG, but it is not good for cryptographic purposes. (Its state is observable and, more importantly, predictable after some 600+ iterations, which isn't a whole lot.) `/dev/urandom` is the _correct_ choice for TRNGs on *nixen.As for `rand()`, I personally think it was a mistake to include it as only ever a _minimal_ PRNG -- a _toy_ -- since now we have to put up with its ubiquity. Thank you again for the excellent answer!

Comment: That is very cool! Thanks for the update. If I could upvote again I would. :O)

Answer (score 6):

A note about standards:

- `rand()` is part of the C standard, so it *must* be provided.  Its implementation is unspecified, but in glibc, it uses the same algorithm as `random()`.  From [man 3 rand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand):

  > The versions of `rand()` and `srand()` in the Linux C Library use the same random number generator as `random(3)` and `srandom(3)`,...
- `drand48()` is part of the POSIX standard.  Its algorithm appears to be specified, it must use a 48-bit linear congruential generator with the following formula (according to [man 3 drand48](http://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48)):

  > ```
  >    Xn+1 = (aXn + c) mod m, where n >= 0
  > ```
- `random()` is part of the POSIX standard.  It uses 31 words of state and an unspecified algorithm, according to [man 3 random](http://linux.die.net/man/3/random):

  > The random() function uses a nonlinear additive feedback random number generator employing a default table of size 31 long integers to return successive pseudo-random numbers in the range from 0 to RAND_MAX. The period of this random number generator is very large, approximately 16 * ((2^31) - 1).

So, POSIX has these three random number generators.  The best one is `random()` or `rand()`, which are the same in glibc (but probably not the same on other systems).  The `drand48()` generator is a very simple type (linear congruential) with a relatively small amount of state (48 bits) so it should be avoided.  None of the random number generators discussed here are necessarily suitable for e.g. Monte Carlo simulation, but `drand48()` is probably much worse than `rand()` or `random()`.

### Which one should I use?

I would always avoid `drand48()` because it is a tiny little linear congruential generator with a small state, and it is only available on POSIX systems.  On POSIX systems, `random()` is usually available, and is better.

I would usually avoid `rand()` because on many systems it is a poor generator, often a linear congruential generator that is even smaller than `drand48()`, and its least significant bits on some systems are cyclical.  If you don't need good random numbers, then `rand()` is fine.

I would use `random()` on any POSIX system if I needed random numbers but didn't care very deeply about how they are generated.

You can always use your own random number generator: if you want a *good, portable* random number generator, this is your only choice.  Mersenne Twister has been a popular choice in the past, although smaller generators seem to be popular these days.

Comment: `rand()` is seeded by `srand()`, which takes only a single `unsigned int`, which means there are at most `UINT_MAX+1` possible initial states. Neither the C standard nor POSIX says nothing about `random()` and does not say or imply that `rand()` has 31 integers (of what size?) of internal state. There are real-world implementations of `rand()` (on *BSD systems) where the result consistently alternates between even and odd numbers. Your claim that `rand()` is superior to `drand48()` is unsupported and, as far as I know, untrue.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I only claim that `rand()` is superior on glibc.  If you want more initial states use `random()`.

Comment: I'm not convinced even that much is true (and the question wasn't about glibc). The number of bits of state is not the only measure of quality of a PRNG. If you care which one has better quality, you probably shouldn't be using either one.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's true, but `drand48()` uses a linear congruential generator, which is known to be an especially poor algorithm for generating random numbers.  We could hardly expect `random()` to be worse.

Comment: `16 * ((2^31) - 1)` does not seem large as that is `16 * 2147483647`. A typo somewhere?

Comment: @chux: Yes, it could be a typo in the manpage.  It is also possible that the generator does not use the full period that its state could afford.

Comment: It is a combination of artifact from the age of the man page and ignorance on the part of the authors. Compared to a stupidly-simple PRNG like the `rand()` it is technically _larger_. Compared to something robust like the Mersenne Twister, it is infinitesimal. However, in the case of `random()`, since the algorithm is left to implementation, the actual period could conceivably vary from the man page's text.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: Although `rand()` is also left open to implementation, as mentioned, it is just `int rand() { return (int) random(); }` in glibc.