# Can drand48() ever return 1?

Tags: c, random, posix

The manual of `drand48()` says:

> The drand48() and erand48() functions return non-negative,
>   double-precision, floating-point values, uniformly distributed over
>   the interval [0.0 , 1.0].

([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/drand48.html))

So just for clarification: Does this mean that 1.0 can be returned by `drand48()`? Or does it mean that the return value will be < 1.0?

I'm asking because in a brute force test `drand48()` never seems to return 1.0. It often returns 0, but never 1.0. However, for me the manual of `drand48()` seems to say that 1.0 is indeed a result that could come up, although I haven't been able to make `drand48()` return 1.0 in practice.

Anybody here who can shed some light onto this? Will the result always be less than 1.0 or can it also be equal to 1.0?

Comment: Often 0 is suspicious.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at? The `man` page for `drand48` on my macOS system says “The full 48 bits of r(n+1) are loaded into the mantissa of the returned value, with the exponent set such that the values produced lie in the interval [0.0, 1.0).”

Comment: The [old Open Group page for `drand48`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/drand48.html) does have a closed interval. That may be a bug in the documentation. The [2018 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) seems to have fixed it.

Comment: See my edit for link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"over the interval [0.0 , 1.0]." It is safe to assume mathematical notation of interval. Parenthesis interval ends are exclusive and square brackets interval ends are inclusive. So according to the notation the returned value can be `1.0`.

**However** this is a documentation of an old version and the current ones specify `[0.0, 1.0)` as the interval (which means it can't be `1.0`):

- The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/drand48.html

  lists `[0.0, 1.0]`
- while

  - The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition
    http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html
  - Linux Man Pages - POSIX.1-2001
    https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-drand48/
  - Linux man page -  POSIX.1-2001.
    https://linux.die.net/man/3/erand48

  all list `[0.0, 1.0)`

So I would be inclined to believe `[0.0, 1.0)` is the correct specification. (it could be that the definition changed since SUS2 which is from 1997 or that it is a typo on the page, but I have no expertise on this so I won't weigh in)

---

> in a brute force test drand48() never seems to return 1.0. It often
>   returns 0, but never 1.0.

This seems highly suspicious. `0.0` should be have the same probability to appear as any other number in the interval so "It often returns 0" doesn't look right. Check that you print with full precision.

As a side note be aware that [dran48 and friends are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269428/why-are-drand48-and-friends-obsolete)

Comment: So can we assume that the first link contains a typo? That would confirm my observations that 1.0 indeed never comes up.

Comment: @Andreas I think yes

Comment: @Andreas Since the SUS2 is from 1997 it is also possible that the definition changed since then.

Comment: Is that possible? Aren't those APIs required to be stable?

Comment: @Swordfish ty for the link and yes, it could be. I absolutely don't know

Comment: @Andreas Possible or not, you referenced a very old document that is not really relevant any longer. You could try to find an alternative source of SUS2, though and check.

Comment: @Andreas Everything since at least 2001 (POSIX & Linux man pages) consistently specifies the closed interval, so it veyr much looks like a bug in SuS2 1997 documentation.

Comment: Required by whom, @Andreas?  In practice, standards are sometimes changed.  That includes, but is not limited to, correcting errors and adjusting specifications to match consensus real-world implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a very old POSIX documentation. The POSIX 2017 for [drand48](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) says:

> The drand48() and erand48() functions shall return non-negative,
>   double-precision, floating-point values, uniformly distributed over
>   the interval [0.0,1.0).

This is also consistent with [Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) (which typically represents glibc implementation).

The same appears in [POSIX 2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/drand48.html) too.